# CAPL how to init array with zeros using memcpy

Tags: c, capl

How can I use memcpy in a Vector in CAPL to initialize an array with zeros?
The variable in CAPL is:

```
byte myArray;
```

In C the solution to init the array would be:

```
memset(myarray, 0, sizeof(myarray));
```

How can I do the same in CAPL?

Answer (score 3):

CAPL do not support dynamic allocated arrays/memory and pointers, so you are forced to use statically allocated arrays. You need to know in advance the array length.

To declare array we should use :

**Static Allocation**

```
byte myArray[10];
```

or **Automatic allocation**

```
  const int size = 10;
  byte myArray[size];
```

We can also declare array and initialize it:

```
  byte myArray[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

To initialize array with some values use for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    { 
        myArray[i] = 0; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`memset()` Converts the value to unsigned char and copies it into the block of memory. CAPL does not support `memset()` instead you can use `memcpy()` (copies from one place to another) in CAPL.

```
on sysvar sysvar::x::y
{
  byte data[4];
  byte data1[4];

  struct WrapDword
  {
    dword dw;
  } dwordWrapper;

  int i;
  // initialize byte array with some values
  for (i = 0; i < elcount(data); ++i)
     data[i] = i;

  // Copy bytes from array to a destination type dword.
  memcpy(dwordWrapper, data); 
  write("Bytes as dword: %0#10lx", dwordWrapper.dw); // 0x03020100

  // Copy dword as bytes into data1
  memcpy(data1, dwordWrapper);
  write("dword as bytes: %#lx %#lx %#lx %#lx", data1[0], data1[1], data1[2], data1[3]); // 0 0x1 0x2 0x3
}
```